# Find closest span element with given class within next sibling

Tags: jquery, selector, children

I have a textarea element as follows:

```
<textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional1" name="additional1" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>
```

Then straight after I have HTML as follows:

```
<div>
  <p>Intro</p>
  <p>Additional text: <span class="addedText"></span></p>
<div>
```

I want the span to be completed with the text added in the `textarea`. However, because I have a lot of these repeated, I need to use siblings / parents / children to target these. I wrote the following:

```
$(".additional1").keyup(function() {
  $(this).siblings('div:first').nextAll('.addedText').html($("#additional1").val());
});
```

But this doesn't work. When I remove the `.nextAll('addedText')` then it does work, but obviously replaces the whole div. How do I target this span element with class `addedText`.

Furthermore, I would then need to replace the `#additional1`' so that for each element with this document the contents of the particular `textarea` being used is selected.

I've been playing around for hours with different combinations and I cannot seem to get the selectors right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small tweaks only needed:

```
$(".additional").keyup(function() {
  $(this).next('div').find('.addedText').html($(this).val());
});
```

for

```
<textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional1" ....
```

- change the selector to the class `.additional`
- use `.next("div")` to get the next div
- use `.find(".addedText")` to find child items of that div
- use `$(this).val()` to get the text from the active `textarea`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot... and glad I wasn't too far away ;)